# Customized org-capture-template for Org Capture Extension

Tags: emacs, firefox-addon, org-mode

I am using the great [Org Capture Extension](https://github.com/sprig/org-capture-extension) Firefox addon to directly capture my web links into my Emacs documents.

A minimal org capture template is:

```
(setq org-capture-templates `(
     ("L" "Protocol Link" entry (file+headline "~/web.org" "Links")
      "* [[%:link][%:description]]\n")  

     ;; ... your other templates
))
```

I use this to bookmark articles, in peculiar a lot of them are on 
[arxiv.org](https://arxiv.org/abs/1606.04838). The problem is that arxiv title pages contain [] characters, for instance:

> [1606.04838] Optimization Methods for Large-Scale Machine Learning

This does *not* mix well with the `[[%:link][%:description]]` used in the template to create the org mode link. For instance a capture returns:

```
** [[https://arxiv.org/abs/1606.04838][[1606.04838] Optimization Methods for Large-Scale Machine Learning]]
```

and the **Org-Mode link is broken** because of the brackets in the **"[1606.04838]"** string.

**How to solve this?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The cure is to transform the link `[%:description]` description into a string that does not contain squared brackets []. For this we can define a function that transforms the [, ] chars into (, ) ones.

```
(defun transform-square-brackets-to-round-ones(string-to-transform)
  "Transforms [ into ( and ] into ), other chars left unchanged."
  (concat 
  (mapcar #'(lambda (c) (if (equal c ?[) ?\( (if (equal c ?]) ?\) c))) string-to-transform))
  )
```

Then we can use this function into the `org-capture-template`. The [%(sexp) syntax](http://orgmode.org/manual/Template-expansion.html#Template-expansion) is used to evaluate the lisp code into the template:

> %(sexp)     Evaluate Elisp sexp and replace with the result.
>                          For convenience, %:keyword (see below) placeholders
>                          within the expression will be expanded prior to this.
>                          The sexp must return a string.

The modified `org-capture-template` is:

```
(setq org-capture-templates '(

    ("L" "Protocol Link" entry (file+headline "~/web.org" "Links")
     "* [[%:link][%(transform-square-brackets-to-round-ones \"%:description\")]]\n")

    ;; ... your other templates
))
```

Then when you click on the Firefox Org-Capture button the template is correctly expended to

```
** (1606.04838) Optimization Methods for Large-Scale Machine Learning
```

with a well formed Org-Mode link (note that the [1606.04838] was turned into (1606.04838))

Comment: Thanks, I had exactly the same problem.

Comment: @rvf0068 I am happy that it helps I was thinking that I was the only one to do such weird things! :)